# Attaching plywood to laminated particle board

Tags: adhesive, plywood, particle-board

I am connecting a piece of laminated particle board to a piece of plywood. Both 5/8” and 2 x 5’. One piece will go on top of the other piece.

In addition to a whole bunch of screws driven through the plywood into the particle board, I’m thinking glue is a good addition. But I’m not sure what sort of glue would be a good candidate.

Because of where I live (Thailand), options can be limited so perhaps you can think of an alternative in case the ideal options doesn’t exist.

Thanks for the help!

Added clarification: I’m building the top of a workbench, where I’m using the top laminated particle board to match the look of my computer desk and add the plywood layer for strength. I have support on the two outsides with two drawer blocks a foot wide, and a 3’ span of the bench where there is no support. The bench will be used for soldering, Dremel-type work, etc.

Added clarification: the particle board in question is laminated on two sides, so there is no ‘wood to wood’ adhesion possible.

Comment: I would use an construction adhesive with particle board as honeydo suggests, particle board can swell with water based glues like wood glue so if products like liquid nails are available that will provide the greatest strength, make sure to clamp together or screw so the adhesive is evenly squished out for greatest strength.

Comment: Thanks, Ed. It’s laminated particle board so I’m not sure water would go through the melamine?

Comment: Is the melamine the working surface? I am referring to the glue surface water based products can cause particle board to swell you did not mention that the particle board was coated (have you accepted any answers? ) looks like a lot of questions with no accepted answers.

Comment: Both sides are coated. Sorry, I’ve never seen one-side laminated boards so wasn’t aware they exist.

Comment: Rob since melamine is not like wood a liquid nails Type product would be more critical (you did state particle board to match your desk but we did not know the particle board was coated until the edit. + for accepting.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote “laminated particle board” since the first post. Didn’t know that had multiple meanings. I thought laminated always meant melamine or Formica or something.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “more critical”? Liquid nails is not the right kind of product, or the recommendation for such a product over something else is even stronger?

Comment: No that it is the right material I did not think and the answer did not think your question was clear until the edit , Formica or melamine and wood glue would be a disaster , wood glue and particle board may work but could cause swelling. Liquid nails will work with both surfaces So knowing the surfaces was critical for a good bond.

Comment: Great, thanks very much to both you and HoneyDo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not clear on the circumstances or the purpose for attaching them. But to answer your question any type of good quality construction adhesive is a very good method of attaching two panels of that size. you can add some screws for reinforcement.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I’ve used this method of adding strength with plywood when placing a 60lb coffee machine on a little IKEA table. It is absolutely rock solid and has worked a treat. There, I used no adhesive but just screws every 4 inches or so in every direction. This means both bits of wood need to bow at the same time and start ripping out a bunch of screws all at the same time, which has not yet happened. I figured the glue would add even more strength. Added further clarification in the original post.

Comment: If you like the answer please upvote or accept it this helps others to find answers to questions they may have that are similar.

Comment: I’ve just done so.

Comment: @Ed Beal - Just caught up with this dialogue. Thanks for clarifying with Rob.